# Problema Para Sobrescrever Valor

Tags: python

Não estou conseguido sobrescrever o self.ValorBase na classe BaixaRenda. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
te = 0.25588
tusd = 0.25971
icms = 0
desc_te = te - (te * 0.10 / 100)
desc_tusd = tusd - (tusd * 0.30 / 100)

class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, vb):
        self.ValorBase = vb * (te + tusd)
        self.NomeClasse = self.__class__.__name__

        def valorIcms(self):
            return self.ValorBase * icms

        print('{:^40}'.format(self.NomeClasse))
        print(vb)
        print(f'{self.ValorBase:.2f}')
        print(f'{self.valorIcms():.2f}')

class BaixaRenda(Cliente):
    def __init__(self, vb):
        Cliente.__init__(self, vb)
    
        if vb <= 220:
            self.ValorBase = vb * (desc_te + desc_tusd)

    def valorIcms(self):
        return self.ValorBase * icms

#Programa Principal
kwh = int(input('Valor Gasto: '))
b = BaixaRenda(kwh)
```

Comment: sim, ele sobrescreve, mas para ver o novo valor tem que fazer um novo print, e eu queria que o novo valor aparecesse no print que está na classe cliente

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz algumas modificações no código:

- Endentei a função local `valorIcms()` para que se tornasse um método da classe base `Cliente`, pois da maneira que havia sido declarada era uma função local pertencente ao escopo do constructor da classe.
- Criei um método para imprimir um relatório aproveitando umas chamadas do builtin print soltas na classe `Cliente`.
- Removi a sobrescrição do método `valorIcms()` pois a sobrescrição não acrescentava em nada.

Exemplo:

```
te = 0.25588
tusd = 0.25971
icms = 0
desc_te = te - (te * 0.10 / 100)
desc_tusd = tusd - (tusd * 0.30 / 100)

class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, vb):
        self.ValorBase = vb * (te + tusd)
        self.NomeClasse = self.__class__.__name__

    #Identei a função local para que se tornasse um método da classe base.
    def valorIcms(self):
        return self.ValorBase * icms
        
    #Criei um método para printar um relatório
    def relatorio(self):
        print('{:^40}'.format(self.NomeClasse))
        print(f'Valor base: {self.ValorBase:.2f}')
        print(f'ICMS: {self.valorIcms():.2f}')

class BaixaRenda(Cliente):
    def __init__(self, vb):
        Cliente.__init__(self, vb)
    
        if vb <= 220:
            self.ValorBase = vb * (desc_te + desc_tusd)    
    
    #Removi a sobrescrição do método valorIcms

kwh = int(input('Valor Gasto: '))
b = BaixaRenda(kwh)
b.relatorio()  #Imprime o relatório
```

<sup>Teste o código no [COLAB](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZW2LYjQ1AwZpKu6B5dEIke3It3QJXmrM?usp=sharing)</sup>